# Python 3 Rock Paper Scissors with user input being stored to make it more challenging

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on Rock, Paper, Scissors in Python 3. I need help trying to implement where the computer keeps track of the users choices so it can tell what the player favors and have an advantage over the player. I also have the computer choosing random using an integer but I need to make the players choice a lowercase 'r' 'p' 's' and a 'q' to quit so it can check for invalid entry and display message and ask again. I don't want to use integers for the player.
Here is what I have:

```
import os
import random
import time

#global variable
#0 is a placeholder and will not be used
choices = [0, 'rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
player_wins = 0
computer_wins = 0
tie_count = 0
round_number = 1
keep_playing = True


# sets cls() to clear screen
def cls():
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')

# function to display stats
def stats():
    print("Current Statistics:")
    print("Player Wins: {}".format(player_wins))
    print("Computer Wins: {}".format(computer_wins))
    print("Tied Games: {}\n".format(tie_count))


# function to check outcome
def game_outcome(player, computer):

    #this makes the variables global, else you'll get error 
    global player_wins, tie_count, computer_wins

    if computer == player:
        print("It's a tie!\n\n")
        tie_count += 1  # incraments tie

    # checks all possible win conditions for player. and if met, declares player a winner. If not, declares compute the winner.
    elif (player == "rock" and computer == "scissors") or (player == "paper" and computer == "rock") or (player == "scissors" and computer == "paper"):
        print("Player wins\n\n")
        player_wins += 1  # incraments player's wins

    else:
        print("Computer wins!\n\n")
        computer_wins += 1  # incraments computer's wins


# clears screen
cls()

print("Let's play Rock Paper Scissors!")

# 3-second time out before clearing and asking for input
time.sleep(3)

while keep_playing == True:

    # make computer choice random from defined list. Only selects a range of 1-3 ignoring the "0" placeholder
    # this is because the user selects a number, instead of typing the weapon, and that number pulls the weapon from the list
    computer = random.choice(choices[1:4])

    cls()

# prints starting of round and shows stats
    print("+++++++++++++[Starting Round {}]+++++++++++++\n".format(round_number))
    stats()

# ask for player input
    player = input("What is your choice?\n(1) Rock\n(2) Paper\n(3) Scissors?\n\nEnter the number before the weapon of choice:")
    player = choices[int(player)]

    cls()

    print("\n\nThe player's choice: [{}]\n".format(player))
    print("The computer's choice: [{}]\n\n".format(computer))

    game_outcome(player, computer)
    round_number += 1


# ask if player wants to play again. If not, stop
    play_again = input('Would you like to play again [y/n]? ')
    if play_again.lower() == 'n':
        break
print("Thanks for playing!")
```

Comment: Please try to post a **Minimal**, Complete and Verified Example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try using a dictionary:

```
# put this with the imports at the top
import sys

# replace `choices` at the top
choices = {'r': 'rock', 'p': 'paper', 's': 'scissors', 'q': 'quit'}

# get computer choice
# replaces `computer = random.choice(choices[1:4])`
computer = random.choice(['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'])

# ask for player input
# replace these two lines of code:
# player = input("What is your choice?\n(1) Rock\n(2) Paper\n(3) Scissors?\n\nEnter the number before the weapon of choice:")
# player = choices[int(player)]
while True:
    try:
        player = choices[input("What is your choice?\n(r) Rock\n(p) Paper\n(s) Scissors?\n(q) to quit.\n\nEnter the letter before the weapon of choice: ")]
        if player == 'quit':
            sys.exit(0)
        break
    except KeyError:
        print('Please try again.')
```

Comment: And `random.choice(choices.keys())` for computer.

Comment: @doriclazar You need to do `random.choice(list(choices.keys()))` in Python 3. This can even be simplified to `random.choice(list(choices))`. Also, do you mean `.values()`, not `.keys()`? Another thing to take into account is that `'q': 'quit'` is an item of `choices`, so `random.choice(['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'])` is probably the best option.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. Either I'm still not getting it right or I don't know how to place it in my code. My apologies if I sound thick headed I'm just starting out and only 12 weeks into learning. Here is what I tried. import os
import random
import time
import sys

#globalA variable
#0 is a placeholder and will not be used
choices = {'r': 'rock', 'p': 'paper', 's': 'scissors', 'q': 'quit'}
player_wins = 0
computer_wins = 0
tie_count = 0
round_number = 1
keep_playing = True

Comment: Sorry I didn't get to finish what I was typing. Thank you for your replies. Either I'm still not getting it right or I don't know how to place it in my code. My apologies if I sound thick headed I'm just starting out and only 12 weeks into learning. Here is what I tried. I imported sys at the top. I changed my choices to choices = {'r': 'rock', 'p': 'paper', 's': 'scissors', 'q': 'quit'} and I tried to add the code for error and I guess I don't know or don't get where to add the while True on down code because everything I've tried doesn't work. Thanks again for the input from all.

Comment: @Mike I will edit my answer to show exactly where you need to place this

Comment: Do I have to use the comment box? I can't show my edits and errors in the comments. I did what was posted as an answer but I still have errors that would be easier to show.

Comment: You could either edit your question or give a Pastebin link.

Comment: Replace lines 64+65 with my code that deals with player input. (And remove the code that you inserted in lines 80-87.)

Comment: @Mike Sorry for the delayed response. It looks like your Pastebin has been removed. Can you take a look/reupload?

Comment: I've messed with it and messed it up so I had to do it over. Your code is in there but no error this time. It just doesn't run for me now. I don't know what to do. pastebin link: https://pastebin.com/1B4kaaE3

Comment: Lines 64 to 78-ish should be indented one more level. They should be within the main game loop (`while keep_playing == True:`).